# navigateToURL dont works

Tags: flash, navigatetourl

I used this code for a long time. It works perfectly. Now, I make php 5.4. It saves the picture but it doesn't go to the site daten.php. When I click at save only save the picture nothing else.

```
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");       
//Create the thumbnail file name
var dotLoc:Number = currentImageName.lastIndexOf(".");
var prefix = currentImageName.substr(0, dotLoc);
var ext = currentImageName.substr(dotLoc);
var thumbName = prefix + "_thumb" + ext;

// Send the data out to PHP to be saved
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://www.domain/datei.php?name=" + thumbName);
jpgURLRequest.data = jpgData;
jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var jpgURLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();       
jpgURLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, saveComplete);
jpgURLLoader.load(jpgURLRequest);
navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest,"_blank")
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly the data is saved on the server but the navigateToURL() is not working ? I've heard of some problems in Chrome browser related to that and also some popup blockers might block navigateToURL().

Nowadays it is better to use JavaScript via ExternalInterface to open up new pages (naturally, it will only work in a browser, not in the standalone flash player andyour users have to have Javascript enabled in the browser which is the default):

```
ExternalInterface.call("window.open", "http://www.domain/datei.php?name=" + thumbName, "_blank");
```

Comment: Yes the data (jpg) is saved but the datei.php is not loading. I try this ExternalInterface.call("window.open", "http://www.domain/datei.php?name=" + thumbName, "_blank");  but no different

Comment: Are you sure that it is not a popup blocker that blocks it ? Does navigateToURL() work in a standalone flash player (not in a browser)? Also, try to use the navigateToURL() again and set the allowScriptAccess to "always" in your swf embed params

Comment: thank you for your help. i go crazy, because i cant stop before it works. it works at the safari browser. i tested now also this http://skovalyov.blogspot.ae/2007/01/how-to-prevent-pop-up-blocking-in.html you can see my "only safari working example" here: http://www.ausdrucken.eu/kalender/foto/kueche-foto.php

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your object embedding - this embed seem to work for me (tested in Chrome):

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="TestActionScript">
    <param name="movie" value="ThumbCreator.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="ThumbCreator.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 6]>-->
    <p> 
        Either scripts and active content are not permitted to run or Adobe Flash Player version
        11.4.0 or greater is not installed.
    </p>
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" />
        </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```